# Is it possible to use distinct supervisor (config) for each user (directory) individually?

Tags: supervisord

Is it possible to use distinct supervisor configuration for each account on the server. So that every user can use supervisor with different specification on his account. I mean instead of using all the same config file on the server they using a local copy of the conf file and run it separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I came across with an article by Peter Ojo in [medium](https://medium.com/@RealPete01/setting-up-supervisor-on-a-shared-hosting-without-root-access-1d564e535d08) that in some way answered my question. It is actually about installing supervisor on a shared hosting but I guess it will do it.

> What you need to do is use the — install-dir flag to install
>   supervisor in a custom location to which your user has full access.
>   You can use the bin directory in your subfolder, i.e.
>   /home/yoursiteuser/bin, or create it if it doesn’t already exist. Add
>   this directory to the PYTHONPATH environmental variable by running the
>   following command;
>
> `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/yoursiteuser/bin`
>
> Now you can verify that you have your custom bin directory in the
>   PYTHONPATH environmental variable by typing
>
> `echo $PYTHONPATH`
>
> **ACTUALLY INSTALLING SUPERVISOR**
>
> Now you can install Supervisor using the easy_install command like so
>
> `> easy_install — install-dir=/home/yoursiteuser/bin supervisor` This
>   should successfully install Supervisor on your server. Yaay!
>
> **USING SUPERVISOR**
>
> To use supervisor, you first need to create a configuration file with
>   the sample configuration. You can do this by running the following
>   command:
>
> `echo_supervisord_conf > supervisord.conf` This will create the
>   configuration file named supervisord.conf in the current directory.
>   Now you can run supervisor like so;
>
> `supervisord –c supervisord.conf` The -c flag tells supervisor where to
>   find the configuration file, in this case it’s right there in the same
>   current directory.